# How do you fix the screen size of raspberry Pi 7" screen

Tags: screen

So I set uncommitted over scan in the config.txt file like I found on Google, but still didn't fix it.

How do I get all of my screen to display? It's a 7" screen.  I had a 2.8" display... used the ads fruit easy install for that one. Did it change something else somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

From your post, it isn't clear what resolution your screen is, but that is pretty important. I'm not sure if changing the overscan values will affect the resolution the pi is putting out, but what I did is uncommented `Framebuffer_width` and `Framebuffer_height` and changed the values to the width and height of my screen in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know the screen came with a config file. Here is the file if anyone needs it. I was in a hurry when I posted the question and was curious if it was something simple, which it was...

```
# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0

max_usb_current=1
# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking,     or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.